# Why does splice() behave weird?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to flatten multiple arrays into one and remove duplicate elements in the array for an exercise from FCC.

Specifically, the splice method shows one thing in the console but acts differently. Can anyone tell me why splice() is not deleting the the duplicates that I have identified with the nested loop?

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var arr1 = arguments; 
  newArr= [];

  for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    for(var l=0; l<arr1[i].length; l++){
      newArr.push(arr1[i][l]);
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
  for(var t=0; t<newArr.length; t++){
    for(var p=0; p<newArr.length; p++){
      if(newArr[t]===newArr[p+1]){
      console.log("without splice ", newArr[p+1]);
      console.log("with splice ", newArr.splice(newArr[p+1],1))
        newArr.splice(newArr[p+1],1);
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

Will output [4,1].
But should output [1,3,2,5,4]

**first Iteration Log:**
without splice  1
with splice  [3]

**Second:**
without splice  1
with splice  [2]

**Third:**
without splice  2
with splice  [4]

**Fourth:**
without splice  1
with splice  [2]

Comment: How is `splice` _"behaving weird'_ in the console here?  You're not logging any statement/expression related to it apart from the final result.

Comment: @Pineda   console.log("without splice ", newArr[p+1]);
  console.log("with splice ", newArr.splice(newArr[p+1],1))

Comment: please edit your question to provide the context of your comment.

Comment: `splice` with mutate the array you are calling it on.  That is, you are altering the array as the loop iterates.  Log out `newArr` above 'without splice' log to see what I mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three errors here:

1. There's no need to use `p+1` here. Just use `p`.
2. `splice` expects an index as its first argument, but you are passing the *value being considered for removal* as an index to perform the removal. This is doesn't make sense. Instead of `.splice(newArr[p], 1)` you need `.splice(p, 1)`.
3. You do not stop a value from being considered against itself as a potential duplicate. Your `if` condition must also include the condition `... && p!=t` since `newArr[t]===newArr[p]` will always be (uselessly) true in case that `t` equals `p`

Comment: This is true, but giving away the answer as OP didn't ask for a full answer to the algorithm, or maybe I'm being narrow minded - Also upvoting for the sake of your answer's accuracy

Comment: Completely unrelated: love your conway's game of life profile description :D

Comment: @apsillers You are right, I have changed all 3 things you mentioned plus there was a 4th problem with the algorithm: As I was spilicing the array the p index would skip one element on every shortening of the array. So to overcome that, I added **p-=1;** at the end of the condition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an array in its loop is something is not recommended. If you don't have to use splice, just create a brand new array and push values by searching and if not already exists in it.

```
function uniteUnique() { 

  var newArr = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) { 
    var arr = arguments[i];
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) { 
      if(newArr.indexOf(arr[j]) == -1) { 
        newArr.push(arr[j]);
      } 
    } 
  } 

  return newArr;
} 

console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In respect to the removing duplicates "in place" of your approach, splice is working fine and your algorithm is almost good, try to debug through each step of the iterations after the flattening, to remove the duplicates.

You are looping n squared times (because p = t and you iterate p * t times).
But, something is not doing what you want to, have a look at these:

```
if(newArr[t]===newArr[p+1]){ // HERE IT WON'T DO WHAT YOU WANT
```

I'm not going to give away the answer unless you mention it, I'm just trying to demonstrate that the problem does not rely with splice itself, rather than your algorithm.

The other line that you would need to modify would be this one

```
newArr.splice(newArr[p+1],1);
```

Basically with a few changes in these two lines, you would reach the goal to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your encouragement. I didn't give up and with your hints and that of @-apsillers I got the script to work.